# how to add characters that aren't alphanumeric

Tags: c++

I have the program working the way I want handling only alphanumeric values but I also wish to create an exception of also allowing periods, hyphens, and underscores. However I want to negate all other characters as illegal.

```
void AccountData::assignAccount()
{
    std::cout << "Input Account Name: ";
    std::string inputAccount;
    std::getline(std::cin, inputAccount);
    std::string useAccount = inputAccount.substr(0, 15);

    if (std::all_of(begin(useAccount), end(useAccount), std::isalnum)) varAccount = useAccount;
    else
    {
        bool valid = true;

        while (valid)
        {
            std::cout << "\nAccounts can only contain alphanumeric values with exceptions of _-.\n\nInput Account Name: ";
            std::getline(std::cin, inputAccount);
            useAccount = inputAccount.substr(0, 15);

            if (std::all_of(begin(useAccount), end(useAccount), std::isalnum))
            {
                varAccount = useAccount;
                valid = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own predicate and use it with `all_of` like this:

```
bool myFun(char a)
{
    return (isalnum(a) || a=='_' || a=='-' || a=='.');
}
void AccountData::assignAccount()
{
    std::cout << "Input Account Name: ";
    std::string inputAccount;
    std::getline(std::cin, inputAccount);
    std::string useAccount = inputAccount.substr(0, 15);

    if (std::all_of(begin(useAccount), end(useAccount), myFun)) varAccount = useAccount;
    else
    {
        bool valid = true;

        while (valid)
        {
            std::cout << "\nAccounts can only contain alphanumeric values with exceptions of _-.\n\nInput Account Name: ";
            std::getline(std::cin, inputAccount);
            useAccount = inputAccount.substr(0, 15);

            if (std::all_of(begin(useAccount), end(useAccount), myFun))
            {
                varAccount = useAccount;
                valid = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```